# Utf-8 в windows-1251(android)

Tags: android, utf-8

хотел бы узнать больше про кодировки текста в java. На самом деле у меня стоит задача отправить текст в кодировке Widows-1251, но я не знаю как переделать строку в кодировке Utf-8, в данную(Если я прав изначально кодировка именно такой и является).
Вот строка, которую надо перекодировать:

```
String str = "5;500;5000;0;1;";
```

Comment: Конкретно в этой строке ничего перекодировать не надо. Коды всех цифр и знаков препинания в Windows-1251 и UTF-8 совпадают (а также коды всех стандартных букв латинского алфавита).

Comment: @Эникейщик, там будут и строчки с буквами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Критические места в этой теме - это преобразование байтов в символы и обратно. Поэтому нужно иметь в виду, что в Андроиде по-умолчанию используется кодировка `utf-8` и когда нужно иное использовать конструкторы и методы с явным указанием кодировки.
 Например:
[`String.getBytes(Charset)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset))
[`InputStreamReader (in, charsetName)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader(java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String))
[`OutputStreamWriter (out, charsetName)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#OutputStreamWriter(java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String))
и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо, я на самом деле пробовал так, просто не обратил внимание, что надо добавить исключение)